# Ubuntu wont boot

Tags: server

I have tried to use Grub repair and get the following:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149235/

When I boot from a live CD I can see my OS files, etc.

I need help. I have been down fro 1 1/2 days and really need to get back up.

Comment: What disk is `/dev/sda`? Your hard disk? It looks like GRUB is installed on `/dev/sdb`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your bios is set to boot from the first hard disk?

Either change your bios to boot off the second hard disk, physically swap the hard discs around, or install grub on the first hard disc (/dev/sda).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have two hard disks? It seems like Grub is installed in /dev/sdb . If you have two hard disks try switching the Boot Order.